# Iterative data store in extjs

Tags: extjs4.1

I want to create hierarchical tabs ( they could be up to n level) using ext-js 4.1. I am trying to create a store as below, for the tab hierarchy. so I can use a generic method to create tabs. How can i iterate through this store structure to create hierarchical tabs?

Hope the structure below is readable :-) showing each level clearly and the depth for the tabs.

```
"toptab1": [{

"id" : 1000

"name" : "coo",

"child": [{

    "id": 1 ,

        "name": "foo" ,

        "child": [{

        "id" :  11 ,  

                "name": "roo" ,

                "child": [{

                        "id" : 111,

                            "name" : "hoo"

                    },

        {

            "id: 112,

            "name": "poo"

        }]

                  },

                  {

                     "id" : 12 ,

                     "name" : "too"

            }]

},

{

    "id" : 2,

    "name" : "woo",

    "child" :[{

        "id": 21,

        "name" : "soo"

        "child" : [{

            "id" : 211,

            "name" : "boo"

        }]

    },

    {

        "id" : 22,

        "name" : "doo"

    }]

},

{

    "id" : 3,

    "name": "zoo"

}];
```

Comment: formatting is still off, also for future reference post extjs version on the tags. That might help your question to be picked up quickly!

Comment: i have been waiting for a response, but there's none. Is there no way to recursively go through the above mentioned store structure to create hierarchial tabs ?

Comment: are you sure you want to do this (up to n levels) . extjs4 panels are heavy.

Comment: they may not be more than 4 levels, but i need the way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

I would create a model to store the information about your tabs.

Then use a TreeStore to store them in the correct hierarchy.

Then you can do something like.

```
var topLevel = this.getTabStore().getRootNode();
topLevel.cascadeBy(function(tab) {
    //Do what you want with each tab here.
});
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-getRootNode

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-cascadeBy